# Browserstack service / webdriverIO / Automate / Session Name is changing during the test

Tags: continuous-integration, webdriver-io, browserstack

since the lasts versions of webdriverIO with browserstack-service 6.4.7, I am facing some issues with the session name on Browserstack : The Continuous integration is sending a name (with a job unique ID) to Browserstack as a "Session Name" and during the test it changed...

(I can see that the name is the right one at the beginning of the test on Browserstack)

it's very difficult for me to find my way around in the tests as they all have the same name which is the suites or Feature name

have you encountered this kind of problem?

thank you very much for any help !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the session name is being picked up and set from within the framework itself. Have you had the chance to output a few variables to the console from this file, https://github.com/itszero/wdio-browserstack-service/blob/47786feacef79c674e79d812cddb99cb87b2a267/lib/browserstack-service.js#L55 and verify the session name being set?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the WebdriverIO version 7 with Mocha framework and BrowserStack.

As per https://webdriver.io/docs/browserstack-service

Add following in your configuration file:

```
services: [
  ['browserstack', {
    browserstackLocal: false, // Set this flag as per your requirement
  }],
],
```

This will automatically set the session's name to the test suite's name.